# ¿Cómo re-insertar texto con Prepared Statement en MySQL con C?

Tags: sql, c

Veréis tengo el siguiente código escrito en C que usa la API de MySQL para conectarme a una BD. A la hora de insertar me interesa hacerlo con las Prepared Statement de la API y a la hora de insertar texto me sucede lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veréis en el código más delante lo que intento hacer es insertar la palabra "AQUI" al salir del bucle despúes del commit aprovechando el código que ya tengo. El ejemplo es estupido pero he cambiado el texto por provar y de repente: NO FUNCIONA! y no consigo entender porque . El código es:

```
void insertar_usuario(MYSQL *conn, MYSQL_STMT *stmt){
char *stmt_str = "INSERT INTO users (id, token, fecha_registro, ultimo_acceso) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
MYSQL_BIND param[4];
int             *id;                /* SERA NULL PORQUE A.I. */
char            token[26];          /* token aleatorio de 25 caracteres */
unsigned long   token_length;   /*              */
MYSQL_TIME      fecha_creacion;     /*              */
MYSQL_TIME      ultimo_acceso;      /*              */

time_t hora;
struct tm *cur_time;


printf ("Empezamos a insertar datos\n");

if (mysql_stmt_prepare (stmt, stmt_str, strlen (stmt_str)) != 0) {
    print_stmt_error (stmt, "Could not prepare INSERT statement");
    return;
}

memset ((void *) param, 0, sizeof (param)); /* zero the structures */

param[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
param[0].buffer = (void *) &id;
param[0].is_unsigned = 0;
param[0].is_null = 0;

param[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
param[1].buffer = (void *) token;
param[1].buffer_length = sizeof (token);
param[1].is_null = 0;


param[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_DATETIME;
param[2].buffer = (void *) &fecha_creacion;
param[2].is_null = 0;

param[3].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_DATETIME;
param[3].buffer = (void *) &ultimo_acceso;
param[3].is_null = 0;

if (mysql_stmt_bind_param (stmt, param) != 0) {
    print_stmt_error (stmt, "Could not bind parameters for INSERT");
    return;
}
mysql_autocommit(conn, 0);

for(int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++){

    (void) time (&hora); /* get current time */

    /* Damos valores */
    id = NULL;

    strcpy(token, ctime(&hora));
    token[24] = '\0';
    token_length = strlen(token);
    param[1].length = &token_length;

    cur_time = localtime(&hora);
    fecha_creacion.year = cur_time->tm_year + 1900;
    fecha_creacion.month = cur_time->tm_mon + 1;
    fecha_creacion.day = cur_time->tm_mday;
    fecha_creacion.hour = cur_time->tm_hour;
    fecha_creacion.minute = cur_time->tm_min;
    fecha_creacion.second = cur_time->tm_sec;
    fecha_creacion.second_part = 0;
    fecha_creacion.neg = 0;

    ultimo_acceso.year = cur_time->tm_year + 1900;
    ultimo_acceso.month = cur_time->tm_mon + 1;
    ultimo_acceso.day = cur_time->tm_mday;
    ultimo_acceso.hour = cur_time->tm_hour;
    ultimo_acceso.minute = cur_time->tm_min;
    ultimo_acceso.second = cur_time->tm_sec;
    ultimo_acceso.second_part = 0;
    ultimo_acceso.neg = 0;

    if (mysql_stmt_execute (stmt) != 0) {
        print_stmt_error (stmt, "No se ha podido ejecutar la sentencia SQL");
        mysql_rollback(conn);
        return;
    }

    printf("%s\n", "Datos insertados correctamente!!");
    mysql_commit(conn);
    sleep(1);
    /* POSIBLE SOLUCION PEGANDO AQUI */

}

mysql_autocommit(conn, 1);

/* POSIBLE SOLUCION PEGANDO AQUI */
/* Damos valores */
id = NULL;

strcpy(token, "AQUI");
token[4] = '\0';
token_length = strlen(token);
fprintf(stdout, "strlen(\"%s\") = %lu\n", token, strlen(token));
param[1].length = &token_length;

cur_time = localtime(&hora);
fecha_creacion.year = cur_time->tm_year + 1900;
fecha_creacion.month = cur_time->tm_mon + 1;
fecha_creacion.day = cur_time->tm_mday;
fecha_creacion.hour = cur_time->tm_hour;
fecha_creacion.minute = cur_time->tm_min;
fecha_creacion.second = cur_time->tm_sec;
fecha_creacion.second_part = 0;
fecha_creacion.neg = 0;

ultimo_acceso.year = cur_time->tm_year + 1900;
ultimo_acceso.month = cur_time->tm_mon + 1;
ultimo_acceso.day = cur_time->tm_mday;
ultimo_acceso.hour = cur_time->tm_hour;
ultimo_acceso.minute = cur_time->tm_min;
ultimo_acceso.second = cur_time->tm_sec;
ultimo_acceso.second_part = 0;
ultimo_acceso.neg = 0;

if (mysql_stmt_execute (stmt) != 0) {
    print_stmt_error (stmt, "No se ha podido ejecutar la sentencia SQL");
    return;
}

printf("%s\n", "Datos insertados correctamente!!");
}
```

Gracias a todos de antemano!

**ACTUALIZADO**

Me he dado cuenta que el problema esta en la longitud del texto que estamos enviando y es posible que tenga que volver a hacer:

```
mysql_stmt_prepare()
mysql_stmt_bind_param()
```

Pero entonces, eso significaría que hay que saber la longitud del texto que vamos a enviar antes de ejecutar `mysql_stmt_bind_param()` y que `param[1].length = &token_length;` no sirve de nada, pues al salir del bucle lo tengo de nuevo y nada (cuando el `fprintf` da el valor esperado 4)

**POSIBLE SOLUCIÓN - ¿POR QUÉ?**

He actualizado el código, si copio y pego este fragmento de código:

```
if (mysql_stmt_bind_param (stmt, param) != 0) {
        print_stmt_error (stmt, "Could not bind parameters for INSERT");
        return;
}
```

En las partes del código que pone `/*Posible solucion pegando aquí */` (solo en 1 de las 3, las ponga en cualquiera funciona) Obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay varías entradas de las diversas pruebas, fijarse en las que pone claramente AQUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a esta declaración:

```
char token[26];
```

¿Por qué haces esto?

```
strcpy(token, ctime(&hora));
token[24] = '\0';
token_length = strlen(token);
```

Si estás asumiendo que el buffer es de longitud 26 lo lógico sería, al menos, setear `token[25]` para evitar perder un byte. Por otro lado, si tienes que setear ese valor en concreto a 0 en vez dejar que sea el propio `strcpy` quien finalice la cadena es porque estás escribiendo fuera del buffer... ¿No sería más lógico entonces usar la función segura `strcpy_s`?

```c++
strcpy_s(token,sizeof(token),ctime(&hora));
// token[24] = '\0' <-- SOBRA!!!
token_length = strlen(token);
```

Por otro lado...

```
strcpy(token, "AQUI");
token[4] = '\0';
```

Si, antes de estas instrucciones `token` contenía algo del tipo (`_` es el sustituto de `'\0'` para mantener la alineación):

```
A B C D E F G H I J _
```

Después de `strcpy` almacenará lo siguiente:

```
A Q U I _ F G H I J _
```

Es decir, para C el buffer contiene únicamente `AQUI`. Lo que tu necesitas es insertar tu texto sin añadir el `'\0'` final porque si no estás perdiendo información. Una forma muy sencilla es con `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(token,"AQUI",4);
```

Por cierto, si te fijas en la siguiente instrucción:

```
param[1].length = &token_length;
```

queda claro que param[1].length es un puntero que apunta a `token_length`, por lo que no tienes que repetir esta instrucción cada vez que cambias el contenido de `token`... con actualizar únicamente `token_length` te vale.

Esto:

```
strcpy(token, ctime(&hora));
token[24] = '\0';
token_length = strlen(token);
param[1].length = &token_length;
```

Se queda así:

```c++
memcpy(token,"AQUI",4);
// token[24] = '\0'; <-- SOBRA
// token_length = strlen(token); <-- La longitud de token no ha variado
// param[1].length = &token_length; <-- el puntero y
```